# Insert Carriage Return in unformatted text file

Tags: c++, text-files, newline, carriage-return

**C++ problem.** I have a text file with no *"carriage return"* or *"new line"*.

All the words are concatenate in a whole single block.

I want to divide the file in lines by substituting every substring *"ABC"* with the *"carriage return"* or *"new line"* character.

P.S: I can't scan the file line by line because the file is actually a single line, bigger than the max value allowed for a single string *(string::max_size)*.

Comment: You can't operate on the file directly. You read from a backup version, parse for `"ABC"` and output other text or `'\n'` alike.

Comment: Is "ABC" string known at coding time?

Comment: Theoretically yes...

Comment: What does it mean "theoretically"? Please explain.

Comment: I can change the string "ABC" with another string in the code program.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the following code:

```
ifstream  input("File_In");
ofstream output("File_Out");

for (unsigned long long int SEEK=0 ; SEEK<(MAX_LIMIT) ; SEEK++)
{
input.seekg(SEEK);
char tmp[4] ;
input.read(tmp,3);
output<<tmp[0];
if (string(tmp)=="ABC") output<<'\n';
};
```